# Empty elements in list item, though object is not empty

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a `ChatHistory` component which renders recent messages. Here is the `ChatHistory` render() function:

```
render() {

    let msgs = this.props.history.map((message) => {
        console.log(message)
          return (
                <li key={ message.date }>
                    <Segment>
                        <img src="public/imgs/kerbal.png" style={{"height" : "40px", "width" : "40px"}} />
                        <p>{message.text}</p>
                        <p>date in millis: {message.date}</p>
                    </Segment>
                </li>
            )
        });
    return (
      <div className="chat-history">
        <ul style={{"list-style" : "none", "padding" : "0 10px"}}>
            {msgs}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

As you can see I am printing out the `message` object to the console. In the object, the `message.text` and `message.date` fields are not empty, and contain the proper values.

When the `<li>` element is rendered, both the `<p>` elements for the text and date are empty. Why would this be?

As a side note, I am getting a single error in the console when the first message is rendered:

> Warning: Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key"
>   prop. Check the render method of `ChatHistory`

As you can see, I am setting a key on the `<li>` element, which is the date of the message in milliseconds (using `new Date().valueOf()`) so they should each be unique. I don't know why that error is then being printed, and further, I am not sure if that error is related to the `<p>` elements not being rendered.

Comment: Can we see the `Segment` code as well?

Comment: The `<Segment>` component is part of `semantic-ui-react`, and is just a container. Removing it does not effect the issue.

Comment: Ah, sorry, not familiar with that library.

Comment: is message.date of type `Date`? or is it a string/number? Edit: nvm you answered this.

Comment: What kind of error are you getting exactly?

Comment: Only the one noted in the post, which may or may not be related to why the contents of the <p> elements are not being rendered.

Answer (score 0):

Just for grins can you try changing your style attribute on the img tag to the following to see what happens:

```
style="height:40px;width:40px;"
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the key on `Segment` instead of `li`.

```
<li>
    <Segment key={ message.date }>
        <img src="public/imgs/kerbal.png" style={{"height" : "40px", "width" : "40px"}} />
        <p>{message.text}</p>
        <p>date in millis: {message.date}</p>
    </Segment>
</li>
```